# how to write not-ascii symbols in symfony .yml files

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Its posible to write russian/french symbols in syfony generator.yml ?

Example:

```
config:
  actions: ~
  fields:  ~

  fields: 
    nstars:  { label: "Моя метка" }

  list:    ~
  filter:  ~
  form:    ~
  edit:       ~
  new:     ~
```

throw errors.

Comment: or how to localize admin-app form labels?

Comment: wiki says: "YAML streams are encoded using the set of printable Unicode characters, either in UTF-8 or UTF-16" - please show your errors

Comment: output::  Fatal error: Class 'BaseSanatoriumGeneratorConfiguration' not found in /var/www/.. symfony not generate this file if have label like   "Моя метка"

Comment: I don't think that this is your problem. Symfony supports these characters out of the box. Have you tried to clear your cache first? Finally the above error on what action is thrown? And please show us the exact error

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the file encoding? Make sure that the file encoding is set up properly. UTF-8 encoded YAML files are working fine for me.

To change the file encoding with Ubuntu use:

> recode ISO8859-15..UTF8 filename